# Recieving data from Android watch to phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying text transfer from watch to phone and phone to watch. I am able to send the data from both the devices to each other, and my watch is able to receive the data too. 
There seems to be some problem in my Receive_Data_Phone class. It doesn't detect any data which i am sending through watch.
I have shared the code and Logcat Output.

Recieve_Data.java

```
public class Recieve_Data extends WearableListenerService {
private static final String TAG = "@@##";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(
            Wearable.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    System.out.println("Inside RecieveData onCreate()");


}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    final List<DataEvent> events = FreezableUtils
            .freezeIterable(dataEvents);
    dataEvents.close();
    System.out.println("Inside OnDataChanged()");

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        ConnectionResult connectionResult = mGoogleApiClient
                .blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(TAG,"WEAR :: Service failed to connect to GoogleApiClient.");
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG,"WEAR :: Service connected to GoogleApiClient.");
    }

    for (DataEvent event : events) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
            Log.d(TAG, "DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED, path = " + path);

                /*          if (Constants.PATH_SERVER_RESPONSE.equals(path)) {
                // Get the data out of the event
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event
                        .getDataItem());
                final String responseString = dataMapItem.getDataMap()
                        .getString(Constants.KEY_TITLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "DataEvent notif responseString: "
                        + responseString);

                Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
                intent.putExtra("message", responseString);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
                        intent);
            } 

             */         

             if (Constant_Vars.PATH_OBJECTIVE.equals(path)) {
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event
                        .getDataItem());
                String msg = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(
                        Constant_Vars.KEY_OBJECTIVE);
                int message = Integer.parseInt(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, "WEAR:: String " + message);


            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unrecognized path: " + path);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MOBILE:: onMessageReceived messageEvent path: "
            + messageEvent.getPath());

    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(Constant_Vars.PATH_OBJECTIVE)) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Working",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unknown request",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Receive_Data_Phone.java

```
public class Recieve_Data_Phone extends WearableListenerService {


private static final String TAG = "@@##";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(
            Wearable.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    System.out.println("Inside RecieveData onCreate()");


}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    final List<DataEvent> events = FreezableUtils
            .freezeIterable(dataEvents);
    dataEvents.close();
    System.out.println("Inside OnDataChanged()");

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        ConnectionResult connectionResult = mGoogleApiClient
                .blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(TAG,"PHONE :: Service failed to connect to GoogleApiClient.");
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG,"PHONE :: Service connected to GoogleApiClient.");
    }

    for (DataEvent event : events) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
            Log.d(TAG, "DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED, path = " + path);

                /*          if (Constants.PATH_SERVER_RESPONSE.equals(path)) {
                // Get the data out of the event
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event
                        .getDataItem());
                final String responseString = dataMapItem.getDataMap()
                        .getString(Constants.KEY_TITLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "DataEvent notif responseString: "
                        + responseString);

                Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
                intent.putExtra("message", responseString);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
                        intent);
            } 

             */         

             if (Constant_Vars.PATH_FLAG.equals(path)) {
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event
                        .getDataItem());
                String msg = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(
                        Constant_Vars.KEY_FLAG);
                //int message = Integer.parseInt(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, "PHONE:: String " + msg);


            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unrecognized path: " + path);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MOBILE:: onMessageReceived messageEvent path: "
            + messageEvent.getPath());

    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(Constant_Vars.PATH_FLAG)) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Working",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unknown request",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think, you may send the same data item, try to add a key-value, like
dataMap.putLong("timestamp", System.currentMillion())
it may work

the reason is : if you send the same data item, google service will not detect the data item is changed, so it will not notify onDataChanged() Method